# XML info shown in Developer tools but none when printed to console in Java

Tags: java, metadata, dicom, urlconnection, println

I am accessing a DICOM metadata file by making a WADO query call.  When I go into the Developer tools of my browser I can see all the metadata information, including ones related to RDSR.

However, in my source code when I simply wishes to print to console all the contents, I noticed that only RDSR metadata information is missing.  I used the same url query as the one I used for the browser, along with this code:

```
URL url = new URL(urlPath);
String userPassword = username + ":" + password;
String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(userPassword.getBytes());
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
uc.connect();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
String strInputLine;
while ((strInputLine = br.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(strInputLine);
}
```

Is there something in my code that is preventing it from printing everything?

Thanks.

Comment: If I were you, I would compare the HTTP headers of both requests (the one that works and the other) and change my code in order to have the exact same HTTP headers in both requests to do the exact same request and then to get the exact same result

Comment: What is the value of your header (eg: `-H "Accept: application/json"`) ? This is not clear from your code.

Answer (score 0):

In conclusion, one of the reasons why working with xmls in code may have missing or funny results is because the xmls may not be plain xmls with one line of data on each line. In other words, it could be that a line is merely the topmost layer acting as an entry point to a tree of data.

Viewing this kind of xml in browser may not look different, but in fact some of the lines of data are nested xml data that are several layers deeper than others, which will require additional recursions when working in code.